# Why did my context becomes null when I execute JavascriptInterface procedure that calls another procedure in another class?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a problem regarding calling a procedure from another class using Javascript Interface.
The problem is, when I call the iniExoPlayer from ExoPlayer class, it gives me NullPointerException...

As I see through log, I found out it's because my context that sent to the iniExoPlayer procedure is null...

I have tried to using `context.getActivity()` in ExoPlayer class, but I'm still getting the error...

Any idea how do I solve this?

**WebAppInterface.java**

```java
    public class WebAppInterface{ 
    public Context context;

    public  WebAppInterface(Context context){
       this.context = context;
    }


    ExoPlayer exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer();



    @JavascriptInterface
    public void show(String vidio){

        exoPlayer.iniExoPlayer(vidio);
    }
```

**ExoPlayer.java**

```java
    public class ExoPlayer extends AppCompatActivity{
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    public static String url;
    public Context context;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

    }


    public void iniExoPlayer(String url){
        Log.d("owo",url);
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_player);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context,"appname"));
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

**Logcat**

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.<init>(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:226)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory.buildVideoRenderers(DefaultRenderersFactory.java:211)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory.createRenderers(DefaultRenderersFactory.java:180)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.<init>(SimpleExoPlayer.java:213)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.<init>(SimpleExoPlayer.java:166)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:386)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:352)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:320)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:214)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:180)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:151)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ExoPlayerFactory.java:141)
        at adnankhairi.webviewer2.ExoPlayer.iniExoPlayer(ExoPlayer.java:37)
        at adnankhairi.webviewer2.WebAppInterface.show(WebAppInterface.java:29)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:328)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(55)] "Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation", source:  (55)
```

Comment: `ExoPlayer exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer();` – Aside from the fact that you never assign the `public Context context;` field in `ExoPlayer`, you cannot instantiate `Activity` classes yourself, and have them work correctly. The base `Context` will never be set – which will lead to further `NullPointerException`s – the lifecycle methods will never run, so there will be no `View`s to find, on top of which, `findViewById()` itself will throw its own Exception, etc. It's not clear what your desired overall design is, but that's the cause of the current issue.

Comment: So, I should initiate this.context in ExoPlayer too?

Comment: It won't help. As I said, directly instantiating `ExoPlayer` is the cause of your current issue. Even if you added `this.context = this;`, you'll still get a `NullPointerException`. I'm not clear on exactly what you mean to do, but if you're just trying to start your `ExoPlayer` from the `WebAppInterface`, then instead, you would use `startActivity()`, and pass your `String vidio` on the `Intent` used there; e.g., altogether, `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ExoPlayer.class).putExtra("video", vidio));`.

Comment: Then, in `ExoPlayer`'s `onCreate()` method, `String video = getIntent().getStringExtra("video");`, `iniExoPlayer(video);`. Follow me?

Comment: Alright, it solved the null pointer problem... maybe u can post this in the Answer section with the explanation of the code?